# Swagger - List of strings in C#

Tags: c#, swagger

I have a problem with Swagger and C#. I have a GET metod that receives a List of strings, and i prove it with Swagger. When I run the application, in Swagger, the param "Lista" is `paramType = body` instead of `query`,and the debugger receives null in this field. How can I do it? Thanks

Swagger output:

```
Parameter   Value    Description    Parameter Type      Data Type
fecha     (required)    Fecha            query           date-time
lista                   Lista            body            array[string]
```

C# Code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Recover some data
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fecha">Fecha</param>
/// <param name="lista">Lista</param>
/// <returns>Information</returns>
[Route("v1/tareas")]
[SwaggerTags("Planificador")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(Tarea))]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, typeof(string))]
//[BearerAuthorizeAttribute]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetTarea(DateTime fecha, List<string> lista = null )
{...}
```

Comment: You either should get parameters from body with the attribute [FromBody] or add the parameter to routing. Right now I'm not sure even your DateTime would work.

Comment: The field DateTime works fine, I always receive a date. The problem is with the list. I never receive any value..

Comment: Try writing (..., [FromBody] List<string> lista ...

Comment: I receive this error :
`{
  "Message": "Error.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Optional parameter  'lista' is not  compatible with'FormatterParameterBinding'.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
 }`

Comment: Without default value, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add attribute [FromBody]:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetTarea(DateTime fecha, [FromBody] List<string> lista)
```

And there is no need to use the default value, it's a reference type if you don't pass anything it will be null anyway.